# .NET 4 Chart, Retrieve range after ZOOM IN/OUT and scrolling

Tags: .net, charts

I am creating Chart in .NET 4, Chart (Visual Basic, VS2010). I enable Zoom (by CursorX, Y) and Scrollbar usage in Chart. I need to know current (for  Ax X) selected (displayed) range after user Zooming IN/OUT and SCROLLING (Scroll bar usage).

I can get Selected range after Zoom IN using method from this topic:

[How to retrieve the selected range in the .Net WinForms Chart Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777087/how-to-retrieve-the-selected-range-in-the-net-winforms-chart-control)

This works good, but only for ZOOM IN, not for Scrolling/Zoom OUT (Zoom out by mouse Click on start position of Scroll bar - Zoom Reset).

I tried to check both `SelectionRangeChangIN/CHANGED` but none of this FIRE/work for ZOOM OUT/Scroll.

Any other idea how to get current Selected (Visible) Range of CHART? 
I can accept (as some approximate solution) to find out First/Last current VISIBLE X Ax labels.

I need current Selected Range for Chart Printing to show start/end date of printed chart.I checked .NET Windows Forms Chart Control tools (with 200 examples and with source code in C/VB) but this is not covered there.

Answer (score 1):

Solved !
I add Mouse Wheel Zoom from this :

[how to enable zooming in Microsoft chart control by using Mouse wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584061/how-to-enable-zooming-in-microsoft-chart-control-by-using-mouse-wheel)

and now I can get current Selection by catching :

1. ZOOM IN by mouse (selection of triangle) when Fire : SelectionRangeChanged/Changing
2. ZOOM OUT/BAR SCROLL when Fire  : AxisViewChanged
3. Mouse Wheel ZOOM IN/OUT when Fire : MouseWheel

I use AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum, AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum that seems OK in all these 3 cases.
Here is sample with some my tracking. Variables dSelDol. dSelHor are Double.

```
Private Sub HDGraf_AxisViewChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ViewEventArgs) Handles HDGraf.AxisViewChanging, _
    HDGraf.AxisViewChanged

    Zobraz("Axis View Changed/ing")
End Sub
Private Sub Zobraz(sS As String)
    Dim dData, dDatb As Date

    Please_wait(_OK, sS, 0)
    dSelDol = HDGraf.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum
    dSelHor = HDGraf.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum
    dData = Date.FromOADate(dSelDol)
    dDatb = Date.FromOADate(dSelHor)
    Me.Ldol.Text = Format(dData, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    Me.LHor.Text = Format(dDatb, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
End Sub
```